# Authlib with Flask Administrative Grant without redirection

Tags: python, authlib

I am trying to connect to a server that is hosted using Microsoft Azure using the Flask OAuth client.

In order to get an authorization code, I need to POST to the authorize_url, the username and password in the body, in addition to response_type, client_id and state. The server then returns the authorization code in the response.

Any ideas on how to get this working?

I've tried many variations of the following however in reading the documentation, I cannot determine a way to send the username, password and retrieve the code from the authorization server:

```
# Python standard libraries
import os

# Third-party libraries
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, session, request, jsonify, render_template

from authlib.integrations.flask_client import OAuth

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True
app.secret_key = os.environ.get("SECRET_KEY") or os.urandom(24)

def ers_compliance_fix(session):

    def _fix(url, headers, data):
        headers = {
            'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': os.environ.get('SUBSCRIPTION_KEY'),
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
        return url, headers, data

    session.register_compliance_hook('protected_request', _fix)

oauth = OAuth(app)
ers = oauth.register('ers',
               api_base_url='https://xxxxx.com',
               access_token_url='https://xxxxx.com/authtoken/Token.php',
               refresh_token_url='https://xxxxx.com/refreshtoken/Token.php',
               authorize_url='https://xxxxx.com/auth/Authorize.php',
               compliance_fix=ers_compliance_fix,
               client_kwargs=None,
               client_id=os.environ.get('CLIENT_ID'),
               client_secret=os.environ.get('CLIENT_SECRET'),
              )

# Get an Access Token (Authorization Code Grant Type)
#
# Get Authorization Code
# POST https://xxxxx.com/auth/Authorize.php
# Header
# { 
#       Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: YOUR_SUBSCRIPTION_KEY
#       Content-Type: application/json
# }
# Body
# {
#       "response_type": "code",
#       "client_id": "YOUR_CLIENT_ID",
#       "username": "ACCOUNT_USERNAME"
#       "password": "ACCOUNT_PASSWORD"
#       "state": "xyz"
# }
# RESPONSE
# "https:\/\/xxxxx.com?code=YOUR_AUTHORIZATION_CODE&state=xyz"

# Exchange Authorization Code for an Access Token
# POST https://xxxxx.com/authtoken/Token.php
# Header
# { 
#       Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: YOUR_SUBSCRIPTION_KEY
#       Content-Type: application/json
# }
# Body
# {
#       "grant_type": "authorization_code",
#       "code": YOUR_AUTHORIZATION_CODE,
#       "client_id": "YOUR_CLIENT_ID",
#       "client_secret": "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET",
#       "redirect_uri": "YOUR_REDIRECT_URI"
# }
# RESPONSE
# {
#       "access_token": "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN",
#       "expires_in": 3600,
#       "token_type": "Bearer",
#       "scope": null,
#       "refresh_token": "YOUR_REFRESH_TOKEN"
# }

@app.route('/')
def index():
        resp = ers.authorize_redirect(None, username=os.environ.get('USER_ID'), password=os.environ.get('PASSWORD'))
        token = ers.authorize_access_token()
        print(token)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(ssl_context='adhoc', host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, debug=True)
```

Comment: Hi JFMuller, and welcome to Stack Overflow! When you say "Any ideas on how to get this working?", which part do you mean? Have you tried anything to get this working? It sounds like you need to POST appropriate details to the authorize_url - have you tried this? There are many external resources on how to make post requests in Python, if you are unsure how to go about this I would suggest starting there.

Comment: Thanks Oliver, the above code results in this error:
    'code': request.args['code'],
  File "/home/jfmuller/flask-by-example/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/datastructures.py", line 442, in __getitem__
    raise exceptions.BadRequestKeyError(key)
werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.

Comment: I wrote my own custom authorize routine to get the authorization code, that redirects to the callback with the code and state satisfying Authlib.

Comment: The last issue I have is that the "register_compliance_hook" does not alter the headers as I attended. How would I modify all headers to include the subscription key using the Authlib api's?